# Difficulty locating the objects in application mentioned in Java Profiler

Tags: java, weblogic, profiler, yourkit

I am using YourKit Java profiler for my web application which is hosted on Weblogic.  I am investigating a memory leak currently.  The profiler shows some quarter million char[] objects that are occupying 25% memory.

I tried looking into my application as to where these char[] objects are created.  Surprisingly, I didn't find any.  Am I doing something wrong here?  Is Weblogic internally creating these Array objects?

How do I locate in my application the exact piece of code that is creating these objects?
Thanks.

Regards,
Siddharth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably these character arrays form the internal part of a java.lang.String. You should ask your profiler to give you an overview of the strings that are currently in memory and whether there are many duplicates.

Comment: remember also, that strings that are constants will never be garbage collected, and so the char[]'s that are part of those Strings will not be eligible either.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea about it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Roland is right on about the char[]s probably being in Strings. I would recommend using [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) for a static analysis of your code. This usually finds a lot of good stuff. Something else you should do is look in your session objects since those are more persistent.

I don't know about YourKit so I can't comment on actually tracing down allocation sources, sorry.